# natbib vs \setcitestyle

Tags: natbib

According to the `natbib` manual you can either set options via package option of by giving them to `\setcitestyle`, how ever they do not give the same result

Try the MWE below with either

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{
  super,
  numbers,
  square,
}
```

or

```
\usepackage[super,numbers,square]{natbib}
```

the later gives me what I want (equiv to `\textsuperscript{[1]}`) but in the situation we are trying to solve, we cannot give options directly to `natbib` (I know I can just load natbib manually earlier, but that is not the point here, both solutions ought to give the same results).

Any idea why?

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xxx.bib}
\@article{xxx,
  title={My Title},
  author={An Author},
  year={2017},
  pages={92--93},
  publisher={My Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents*}
% shouldn't the below be equivalent to 
%\usepackage[super,numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{
  super,
  numbers,
  square,
}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}

test\cite{xxx}

 \bibliography{xxx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, hint: `\setcitestyle` does not like spaces, sigh

Comment: That plus you don't want `numbers`, just `square`: will you post that as an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright we are actually trying to use your `achemso` package and the student wanted a very specific style. As I explain in my answer there seems to be a discrepancy in the implementation in `natbib`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question

- The package options and the options in `\setcitestyle` are not implemented in the same manner, `numbers` package option sets `numbers` to true, but `numbers` option to `\setcitestyle` sets `numbers` to true and `super` explicitly to **false**!
- `\setcitestyle{...}` uses its own low level comma parser, and it does not remove white space at the start or end of the keyword.

Therefore

```
[super,numbers,square]
```

is equivalent to

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,square,super}
```

`super` has to go last.

As Joseph mentions `numbers` are probably not needed here, but does not hurt.